# Accessing a method from an inheritance class at the main

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance, methods

This is my code:

```
  class Asignaturas(object):
      def __init__(self,asignatura):
          self.asignatura = asignatura

  class Mate(Asignaturas):
    def mcm(self,num1,num2):
        print("estoy en el mcm\n")
        if(num1>num2):
            x = num1
        else:
            x = num2
        while(True):
            if((x %  num1 == 0) and (x % num2 ==0)):
                mcm = x
                break
            x = x+1
        print("aqui dentro del mcm\n")
        print(mcm)
        return mcm

if __name__ == "__main__":
x = int(input("que asignatura quieres ver? 1. 
Matematica 2.LEnguaje 3.Artes\n"))
if (x==1):
    y = int(input("quieres saber> 1.mcm o 
2.potencia\n"))
    if(y==1):
        num1 = int(input("ingresa un numero:\n"))
        num2 = int(input("ingresa otro numero:"))
        mcm = Mate(num1,num2)
        print(mcm)
        print("el mcm es:",mcm)
```

So What imtrying to do is to access the method mcm from the class Mate, that is a class from the other class Asignaturas. I tried to call it from main but it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "huesos2.py", line 28, in <module>
   **mcm = Mate(num1,num2)**
TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Comment: Buy why are you passing `num1,num2` when it is only expecting `asignatura`?

Comment: Actually, I can't see what you're trying to do here at all. Why is `mcm` a method in a class? What's the point of the Mate class? Why isn't `mcm` just a standalone function which you can just call on its own?

Comment: Im passing num1,num2 to the other class Mate, not to the class Asignaturas

Comment: It is just an assignment for school, I need to include a method inside an  inheritance class, so Mate is from Asignaturas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to first initiate the Mate object by calling the **init**() function from Asignaturas.
Note that it takes 1 argument `def __init__(self,asignatura):` (You don't have to care about `self`)
then you get back an object. You can call mcm to this object with your 2 numbers.

So your code must be something like this:

```
mate = Mate(asignatura)
mate.mcm(num1, num2)
```

Comment: Im sorry, im just starting with python, where and why should I define: mate = Mate(asignatura)

Comment: This is object orientated programming. Every time you have a class you first need to initiate an object before you can work with the class. But I think you should just google something like "object orientated programming beginner" and you get better resources than me.